# GDAL Dockerfiles depending on Apache binary artifacts/packages no longer build successfully

Tags: gdal, docker

I have a web service built on a GDAL Docker image, found [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pkgs/container/gdal):

This is the specific image and tag I'm using:

ghcr.io/osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.8.4

My own Dockerfile based on this image fails to build. I get the following error messages:

```
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/arrow/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/arrow/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
```

Visiting https://apache.jfrog.io/ returns an error. Apparently the host stopped serving the Apache subdomain on jfrog.io recently.

I don't think I'm using Apache Arrow in my own application. How do I get past this?

Answer (score 5):

I found that this is a [known and recurring issue](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/40759) with Apache binary packages. Since I can't afford to have a hosting issue stop my builds, I decided to remove the reference to this repository before I run any package updates during the build process:

```
# remove reference to missing repo
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apache-arrow.sources

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
      build-essential \
....
```

I find that the build completes successfully and my service runs on the new images. Maybe there's a smarter way to do this, but this works for me.